# Proving a vector space (8 axioms) when the condition involves a constant

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I know how to prove that something is a vector space for most cases but I have never been given a case where the condition involves a constant.

I am asked to prove (through the 8 axioms) that the following is a vector space (this is in matrix form, i.e. a on top of b):

(a,b)+(c,d) = (a+c-3, b+d-1)

t(a,b) = (ta-3t+3, tb+t-1)

I hope my question is understandable. I am looking for pointers on how to deal with the constant. E.g. how to prove x+(y+z) = (x+y)+z ?

BTW, we are told that this is indeed a vector space and that it satisfies all conditions.

Comment: What's the obstacle? Did you compute $((a,b)+(c,d))+(e,f)$? Did you compute $(a,b)+((c,d)+(e,f))$? Are they equal or not?

Comment: You just test the associative law using the definition of addition (with its constant) as given to you.

Comment: @Compacto The fact OP is struggling with it proves that it is not useless.

Answer (score 1):

The constant makes the axioms involving zero interesting.
Try working out what your "zero element" is, i.e. which element $\mathbf{z}$ of your vector space satisfies $\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{a}$ for all $\mathbf{a}$ in your vector space.

You don't need to do anything unusual to prove associativity, though. Just say, "Let $(a_1,b_1)$, $(a_2,b_2)$, $(a_3,b_3)$ be any vectors in the vector space", then compute $((a_1,b_1)+(a_2,b_2))+(a_3,b_3)$ and $(a_1,b_1)+((a_2,b_2)+(a_3,b_3))$, and show that they are equal.